# backbone validate method doesn't trigger in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm new to backbone.

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    name: '',
    age: 30,
    occupation: 'fireman'
  },
  validate: function(attrs) {
    console.log(attrs) // this won't trigger? since the model's attr changed;
  },
  run: function() {
    return this.get('name') + ' is running';
  }
})

var p = new Person({name:'James'});
p.set('age',25);
```

I change the model's property but somehow I did not see the console. Why?

Comment: You should have included the Backbone version you're using in addition to the video you're following in your question. Providing every details of your situation is important to get appropriate help and make this thread useful for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the set method to validate by passing validate option.
http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate

```
p.set({age: 25}, {validate: true});
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGHZJDRqhDE&list=PL7Rr5tteQoVQDWruYZuOx9_MXB4sr847H&index=4

Comment: @Sandy the video tutorial uses 0.9.2 which is an old version of Backbone and it didn't have the `validate` option yet.

Comment: @Sandy in **External resources**, you have 2 versions of underscore, one of which is imported after Backbone. To use backbone, you need to import **jQuery**, **underscore** and **backbone** in that order.